# xslt - for-each-group challenge

Tags: xslt-2.0

My challenge is that I have to group everything in the values ​​/ value tags. I have to group every tag `<Value ID="0" AttributeID="att_X">0 - AAAAA</Value>` when there is a value with AAAAA in it.
The values ​​0 - AAAAA, 23 - AAAAA B, 12 - AAAAA C must come together in the output message, What is the best way to do this?

I have tried to group it

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="Entity/Values/Value[@AttributeID='att_PVPP']" group-by="substring-before(substring-after(Entity/Values/Value[@AttributeID='att_X'], '- '), ' ') ='AAAAA'">
```

also tried

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="Entity/Values/Value[@AttributeID='att_PVPP']" group-by="matches(Entity/Values/Value[@AttributeID='att_X'], 'AAAAA')">
```

and

```
<xsl:for-each select="matches(Entity/Values/Value[@AttributeID='att_X'], 'AAAAA')">
```

I have the following input xml:

```
<Entities>
    <Entity Referenced="true" Selected="false" ParentID="P" UserTypeID="V" ID="PVP-1">
        <Name>123456 - 0</Name>
        <Values>
            <Value AttributeID="att_PVPS">2020-10-06</Value>
            <Value AttributeID="att_PVPP">123456</Value>
            <Value ID="0" AttributeID="att_X">0 - AAAAA</Value>
            <Value AttributeID="att_PVPEi">2020-10-06</Value>
            <Value UnitID="Y.unit." AttributeID="C">10</Value>
            <Value ID="2" AttributeID="att_Z">A</Value>
        </Values>
    </Entity>
    <Entity Referenced="true" Selected="false" ParentID="W" UserTypeID="V" ID="PVP-2">
        <Name>789012 - 200</Name>
        <Values>
            <Value AttributeID="att_PVPS">2020-09-16</Value>
            <Value AttributeID="att_PVPP">789012</Value>
            <Value ID="200" AttributeID="att_X">200 - BBBBB</Value>
            <Value AttributeID="att_PVPEi">2020-10-22</Value>
            <Value UnitID="Y.unit." AttributeID="C">200</Value>
            <Value ID="2" AttributeID="att_Z">A</Value>
        </Values>
    </Entity>
    <Entity Referenced="true" Selected="false" ParentID="W" UserTypeID="V" ID="PVP-3">
        <Name>123456 - 0</Name>
        <Values>
            <Value AttributeID="att_PVPS">2020-10-07</Value>
            <Value AttributeID="att_PVPP">123456</Value>
            <Value ID="0" AttributeID="att_X">0 - BBBBB</Value>
            <Value AttributeID="att_PVPEi">2020-10-13</Value>
            <Value UnitID="Y.unit." AttributeID="C">1</Value>
            <Value ID="2" AttributeID="att_Z">A</Value>
        </Values>
    </Entity>
    <Entity Referenced="true" Selected="false" ParentID="W" UserTypeID="V" ID="PVP-4">
        <Name>123456 - 23</Name>
        <Values>
            <Value AttributeID="att_PVPS">2020-10-16</Value>
            <Value AttributeID="att_PVPP">123456</Value>
            <Value ID="23" AttributeID="att_X">23 - AAAAA B</Value>
            <Value AttributeID="att_PVPEi">2020-10-21</Value>
            <Value UnitID="Y.unit." AttributeID="C">1</Value>
            <Value ID="3" AttributeID="att_Z">C</Value>
        </Values>
    </Entity>
    <Entity Referenced="true" Selected="false" ParentID="W" UserTypeID="V" ID="PVP-5">
        <Name>123456 - 12</Name>
        <Values>
            <Value AttributeID="att_PVPS">2020-10-14</Value>
            <Value AttributeID="att_PVPP">123456</Value>
            <Value ID="12" AttributeID="att_X">12 - AAAAA C</Value>
            <Value AttributeID="att_PVPEi">2020-10-16</Value>
            <Value UnitID="Y.unit." AttributeID="C">15</Value>
            <Value ID="2" AttributeID="att_Z">A</Value>
        </Values>
    </Entity>
</Entities>
```

The output must be:

```
<test>
  <test1>
    <value-ID-att_X-att_X>0</value-ID-att_X>
    <lines>
      <line>
        <att_PVPS>2020-10-06</att_PVPS>
        <AttributeID-C>10</AttributeID-C>
        <value-ID-att_Z>2</value-ID-att_Z>
      </line>
    </lines>
  </test1>
  <test1>
    <value-ID-att_X>23</value-ID-att_X>
    <lines>
      <line>
        <att_PVPS>2020-10-16</att_PVPS>
        <AttributeID-C>1</AttributeID-C>
        <value-ID-att_Z>3</value-ID-att_Z>
      </line>
    </lines>
  </test1>
  <test1>
    <value-ID-att_X>12</value-ID-att_X>
    <lines>
      <line>
        <att_PVPS>2020-10-14</att_PVPS>
        <AttributeID-C>15</AttributeID-C>
        <value-ID-att_Z>2</value-ID-att_Z>
       </line>
    </lines>
  </test1>
</test>
```

Comment: I haven't understood your requirement, neither your textual description seems to explain which input elements you want to group by which grouping key nor your sample XSLT snippet seems to make sense nor does the output sample easily allow to see a relation to the input data. So perhaps elaborate more, do you want to group `Entity` elements? Or `Value` elements? What is and what determines a group in the posted output?

Comment: i have adapted my question. I have to group Value elements. That is the only possibility i think,

Comment: Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: I haven't managed to understand in any way what you want to achieve, your XSLT snippets make no sense. For the last, if all you want is select or process certain `Value` elements where the condition for the attribute is true and the content matches some string use e.g. `select="Entity/Values/Value[@AttributeID='att_X'][matches(., 'AAAAA')]"`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen thank you for your answer, That was what i meant. The solution works.